# Ignite loosing table

Tags: ignite

I am running ignite in a kubernetes Environment.
Recently i noticed a mysql table disappear.

Ignite is configured with storageMode on:

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
  <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
      <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

I see no restarts for the ignite service in kubernetes. Is there any other scenario possible, why a table could disappear?

Comment: Do you use Ignite as a cacheStore for MySQL? Could please provide more details about your case? And what do you mean when you say "disappear", you don't see the cache or you've lost your data?

Comment: I manually created a table via DBeaver. From the application i connect via a SQLConnection to the Ignite Host and execute different queries on the table:             
 example: connection = DriverManager.getConnection(igniteHost);  I noticed that the whole table has disappeared. (not the data, the whole table is gone)

Comment: Are you able to query from table from DBeaver? Do you see any other tables? Have your JDBC connection been established correctly?

Comment: No, in dbeaver the table is gone. I had only one table so I cannot see other tables, but I could create a dummy one to observe. The jdbc connection is fine, it works as long as the table is physically there

Comment: So, there is no MySQL, just Ignite SQL, right? Is file system state saved between restarts of your Kubernetes service?